# Set origin point to the center of circle?

Tags: origin

I try every *Set Origin To* and I am stuck.
I would like to move the origin point to the center of it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you select the circle and then press shift-s then a pie menu comes up. You can then press cursor to selection. This should put the 3d cursor in the center. If not, then your circle's origin is in the wrong spot. You can fix this bye, in object mode, press object with the circle selected. The object button is towards the top right. After you press this a dropdown will appear and you can hover over set origin, and then press origin to geometry. This will set the origin to the center of the object. Then you can repeat the step to set the 3d cursor to the selection and then the 3d cursor should be in the center of your circle. Hope this helps!

Comment: Follow every step but still don't work

Comment: I use a simple deform modifier as well

Comment: If you select the mesh in object mode there should be an orange dot. This is the origin of the mesh. Where is the orange dot?

Comment: @BenjaminRoope Take a look at the screenshot: the orange dot is slightly below the 3D cursor. As commented by Gwen, a _Simple Deform_ modifier is used, _Origin to Geometry_ will not work here. If you move the origin, the _Simple Deform_ modifier will not give the same result. But I guess this is no longer relevant after three years.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the origin you could apply the Simple Deform modifier, then follow the steps in the answer by Benjamin Roope.

Comment: This is the simple destructive answer. Problem is, Gwen never stated if she wants to keep the modifier in order to be able to change something later if necessary... but I guess after almost three years this does not matter anyway.

Comment: I also think this is not a good or even complete answer.